# Can I deploy a Java Spring MVC web application without JSP?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I want to deploy a Java Spring MVC web application on a client machine. But I do not want to show my code to them.
Is it possible to give compiled JSPs servlet class files in deployment that can run in Tomcat manager?

Answer (score 1):

You can precompile jsp to classes, check :

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-precompile-my-jsps.html

and

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin.html